# Updates To Firebase Firestore Document Popping View Off Navigation Stack SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI app and using Firebase Firestore as a backend. I am noticing an odd behavior when I update a document in Firestore that results in a view being popped off the Navigation stack each time a field is updated. The Navigation Stack is as follows.

1. MarketplaceView with List Containing ListingRowViews
2. Tapping a row takes you to a ListingDetailView.
3. Tapping a Buy Now button in ListingDetailView takes you to a ConfirmationView.

When updates are made to the document and 1 or 2 is present, the view updates and all behaves as expected. When 3 (ConfirmationView) is present, any updates to the document result in the ConfirmationView being popped off the stack back to 2 the ListingDetailView. Below is the app architecture.

**ListingRepository - Creates a snapshotListener for all Listings in Firestore.**

```
class ListingRepository: ObservableObject {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var snapshotListener: ListenerRegistration?
    
    @Published var listings = [Listing]()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        startSnapshotListener()
    }
    
    func startSnapshotListener() {
        // Add a SnapshotListener to the Listing Collection.
        self.snapshotListener = db.collection(FirestoreCollection.listings).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            } else {
                // Check to make sure the Collection contains Documents
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No Listings.")
                    return
                }
                
                // Documents exist.
                self.listings = documents.compactMap { listing in
                    do {
                        return try listing.data(as: Listing.self)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MarketplaceViewModel - Subscribes to Listings from ListingRepository and creates ListingRowViewModels.**

```
class MarketplaceViewModel: ObservableObject {    
    // Properties
    @Published var listingRepository: ListingRepository = Resolver.resolve()
    
    // Published Properties
    @Published var listingRowViewModels = [ListingRowViewModel]()
    
    // Combine Cancellable
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        
    // Intitalizer
    init() {
        self.startCombine()
    }
    
    // Starting Combine
    func startCombine() {
        listingRepository
            .$listings
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { listings in
                listings
                    .map { listing in
                        ListingRowViewModel(listing: listing)
                    }
            }
            .assign(to: \.listingRowViewModels, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

**MarketplaceView - Creates the List full of ListingDetailViews**

```
struct MarketplaceView: View {        
    @ObservedObject var marketplaceViewModel: MarketplaceViewModel = Resolver.resolve()
        
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView {
            
            List {
                ForEach(self.marketplaceViewModel.listingRowViewModels, id: \.id) { listingRowViewModel in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ListingDetailView(listingDetailViewModel: ListingDetailViewModel(listing: listingRowViewModel.listing))
                    ) {
                        ListingRowView(listingRowViewModel: listingRowViewModel)
                    }
                } // ForEach
                .navigationTitle("Marketplace")
            } // NavigationView
        } // View
    }
}
```

ListingRowViewModel - View model for each row.

```
class ListingRowViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    // Properties
    var id: String = ""
    
    // Published Properties
    @Published var listing: Listing
    
    // Combine Cancellable
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        
    // Initializer
    init(listing: Listing) {
        self.listing = listing
        self.startCombine()
    }
    
    // Starting Combine
    func startCombine() {
        $listing
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .compactMap { listing in
                listing.id
            }
            .assign(to: \.id, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

**ListingRowView - View for each row.**

```
struct ListingRowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var listingRowViewModel: ListingRowViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.listingRowViewModel.listingId)
    } // View
}
```

**ListingDetailViewModel - View model for the detail view.**

```
class ListingDetailViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var listing: Listing
        
    // Initializer
    init(listing: Listing) {
        self.listing = listing
    }
}
```

**ListingDetailView - Detail View For Listing**

```
struct ListingDetailView: View {    
    var listingDetailViewModel: ListingDetailViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.listingDetailViewModel.listing.id)
            NavigationLink(destination: ConfirmationView(confirmationViewModel: ConfirmationViewModel(listing: listing))) {
                Text("Buy Now")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Listing Info")
    } // View
}
```

**ConfirmationViewModel - View model for Confirmation View**

```
class ConfirmationlViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var listing: Listing
        
    // Initializer
    init(listing: Listing) {
        self.listing = listing
    }
}
```

**ConfirmationView - Confirmation View**

```
struct ConfirmationView: View {
    var confirmationViewModel: ConfirmationViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.confirmationViewModel.listing.id)
            Button(action: {
                self.confirm()
            }, label: {
                Text("Confirm")})
        }
        .navigationTitle("Order Confirmation")
    } // View
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to find the problem if you strip the code down to its [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or try using three simple views that produce the same error you're having.

Comment: This code has been stripped to show the minimum structure. The issue is more complex than three simple views. It relates to updates to Firestore documents a MVVM with Resolver. Any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Are you using @DocumentID? Maybe when the item is modified the ID is getting auto-generated.

Comment: I am using @DocumentID. I believe these stay the same. I’ll double check.